# Providing Code Discription Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

A lot of answers have no `'comments'` in the code, specifically answer which have changed the OP script or developed something different.

Example of providing comments in your Answer:

```
    'For each visible cell in Column 2 "Comment"
    For Each cell In ContractRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        'If the Value is "Comment"
        If cell.Value = "Contract" Then

            'Do nothing

        Else
            'Set the Cell value into the Array
            ContainA(i) = cell
            NotContainA(i) = "<>" & cell
            'Increment i
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Next cell
```

Without Comments:

```
    For Each cell In ContractRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If cell.Value = "Contract" Then
        Else
            ContainA(i) = cell
            NotContainA(i) = "<>" & cell
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell
```

Personally I find it good and beneficially, specifically with the orientation of SO and how it is to solve the OP's question.

Providing legitimate commenting in the script is hugely beneficial to any programmer and for future editing.

My Question as stated in the Title, is that is it the norm not to provide answers with comments included in the script?

Comment: A lot of times, I'll use explanation outside of code comments instead.  For example, I often break code into logical pieces with my post instead of with comments.

Comment: "norm"...Meh. In a *code-only* answer they would be recommended but I wouldn't downvote one without them....but then i wouldn't upvote (generally) a code-only answer with them. I would expect a plain text explaination of the code.

Comment: You need comments when the code is not very readable.  Is it *really* a good idea to hard-code a string literal like "Contracts" when it can also be a well-named literal?  Is it *really* a good idea to avoid the `Not` operator in the If statement expression?  Was there *really* a point in abbreviating "Range" to "Rng"?  Was it *really* a good idea to hide how the range creation was hidden so therefore not giving the reader a hint that column #2 was involved?   You can make it better, feeling that you need a comment is your cue.

Comment: Is that answer intended for an absolute beginner level? Putting a comment like `Increment i` on top of `i = i + 1` is exactly the kind of comment I consider to be worse than useless, unless it is for someone who is still learning the most basic mechanics of the language. As Will basically said, but put another way, I think the code without comments is actually easier to digest in this particular case. A nice use of comments should document something a bit higher-level than what one line of straightforward code is doing.

Comment: The first example is completely commented and spaced. The second is no comment  no spacing.  To show the extremes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would only rarely add a comment, only doing if absolutely necessary. I don't write 'i,j,k,a,b,c' code, nor do I write 'clever, compact' code.  I write code that can be easily understood and debugged without extraneous comments.

Also, not adding comments on every line makes the copypasta to homework answer extremely difficult and annoying for those posters whose assignment asks for 'full comments must be provided'.

Answer (score 4):

Adding comments to a code block is left to the user who answers. I do not always provide comments in the code itself, but do attempt to explain *why* I made radical changes, if they were required.

The idea isn't that someone will copy and paste the code that I've provided, but instead read the entire answer an *learn* something.

Comments in the code should be relevant. I'm hoping that the code you provided in this answer is an example, but if it is not, I do not consider your comments relevant at all.

What does

> 'If the Value is "Comment"

tell me, that the following line doesn't (other than the comment is actually *wrong* - "Comment" versus "Contract"?

> If cell.Value = "Contract" Then

In this case, the comment it *harmful*. First, it's your if statement in comment form. Anyone reading the code should be able to figure out what that statement is doing. Second, it is incorrect. Now a future developer needs to figure out if the comment is right or if the code is right.

Another example:

> 'Increment i

versus

> i = i + 1

These types of comments are things you see in a first year student's homework assignment because the instructor requires a certain number of comments. These aren't helpful at all.

Comments should be utilized, on Stack Overflow, to call out areas where code what changed or to briefly explain why a line is doing something complicated. Incrementing a variable is not complicated and isn't helping.

Remember, the idea is to help users. Sometimes, a brief paragraph explaining your logic is more valuable than a short phrase in a code block.